# custom HTML in dash

Tags: html, rest, plotly-dash

So I have a regular dash application and now I want to try and add graphs that are generated from another API, retrieved as HTML from a regular request. I already have some dash components in my app but would like to add the extra graphs provided by another API. Can I "embed" the custom html code I get from the API in my dashbord.

Something like

```
custom_html = r.get(URL_request)
```

Then I get some new HTML:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en-US">\n\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />\n<title>...
```

Which I want to embed in my dash app like:

```
html.Div([
   dcc.Graph(id = "my dash graph")
   html.custom_html(id = "api graph", custom_html.content)
])
```

Comment: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/iframe

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed! @BasvanderLinden